# Find max and min value of BST

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

Hello stackoverflowers, 
i am facing a problem with my function in C, i want to create a function that give me the min and max value in BST.
The problem is when i use this function it returns the same value for min and max:

```
void Find_Min_Max(node *bt,int* maxint,int* minint)
{
    node *tmp = bt;
    if( bt == NULL)
    {
        *maxint = 0;  // Only if the tree contains nothing at all
        *minint = 0;  // Only if the tree contains nothing at all
    }
   if( bt->left)
       return Find_Min_Max(bt->left,&(*maxint),&(*minint));
   *minint = bt->data;
   if( tmp->right)
       return Find_Min_Max(tmp->right,&(*maxint),&(*minint));
   *maxint = tmp->data;
}
```

But when i use it to give me just one result max/min, i delete this part of code, everything work perfectly:

```
if( tmp->right)
    return Find_Min_Max(tmp->right,&(*maxint),&(*minint));
*maxint = tmp->data;
```

Any idea how this will work?.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Doesn't the recursion stop when you find either min or max? i.e. if the min and max are in different halfs, then it would find only one of them.

Comment: What is `tmp`? Shouldn't you be using `bt->right` instead of `tmp`?

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves it's the same the function returns the same value for max and min

Comment: @kuhaku yes i know, but i added another recursion function just when the first finish her work, or this is a wrong method !

Comment: @ZeroOne no the recursion will stop at whichever comes first, min or max.

Answer (score 3):

It's not really easy / intuitive to recursively compute max and min at the same time in the same function. I would even say it's not possible, because those are two completely different traversals.

You should have a function to get the minimum, a function to get the maximum, and call each of them inside `Find_Min_Max`.

This would be a possible approach:

```
int find_min(node *n) {
    if (n == NULL) {
        return 0;

    }
    while (n->left != NULL) {
        n = n->left;
    }
    return n->data;
}
```

`find_max` is similar, but traverses right links only:

```
int find_max(node *n) {
    if (n == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    while (n->right != NULL) {
        n = n->right;
    }
    return n->data;
}
```

Then, `find_min_max()` is easy to code:

```
void find_min_max(node *bt, int *min, int *right) {
    *min = find_min(bt);
    *max = find_max(bt);
}
```

`find_min()` and `find_max()` could be recursive, but the iterative approach has the desirable property of using constant memory (and consequently avoids stack overflows).

Comment: Going only to the left or only to the right assumes the tree is sorted in a particular pattern right?

Comment: @kuhaku It assumes we're talking about a BST, just like the title suggests.

Comment: yes i know those methods, and also we can use recursion in both function, but isn't there any method to merge both recursion functions in one !

Comment: @ZeroOne Like I said, I don't think there is one - or, if there is, it would be extremely painful to debug and implement. Why complicate what is simple?

Comment: Well, i guess i'll use this function with the While loop, Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

To find the minimum value in a BST, you follow the chain of left children from the root until you reach a node with no left child.  That node contains the minimum value (even if it does have a right child).

The algorithm to find the maximum is exactly the mirror image: follow the chain of right children until you reach a node with no right child.  That node contains the maximum value.

It does not make sense to try to perform both traversals at the same time, because they follow completely different paths.  If you want a single function to discover both the minimum and the maximum value, then it doesn't make much sense for that function itself to be recursive.  It could, however, wrap calls to two separate recursive functions, one to find the minimum, and the other to find the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

**Finding min and max value in a BST are very easy. Please check both code snippet below I explain how these codes work.**

```
public int minValueInBST(Node node){
    if (node == null) throw new IllegalStateException();
    Node current = node;
    while (current.leftChild != null) {
        current = node.leftChild;
    }
    return current.value;
}
```

To find the minimum value in BST we have to find the leftmost leaf node because that node contains the minimum value. So at first, we check the root node is null or not if null we throw IllegalStateException otherwise we find the left node, at last, we return the left node value.

```
public int maxValueInBST(Node node){
    if (node == null) throw new IllegalStateException();
    Node current = node;
    while (current.rightChild != null) {
        current = node.rightChild;
    }
    return current.value;
}
```

To find the maximum value in BST we have to find the rightmost leaf node because that node contains the maximum value. So at first, we check the root node is null or not if null we throw IllegalStateException otherwise we find the right node, at last, we return the right node value.

Answer (score 0):

```c
// try this
tree_node *min(tree_node *root)
{
    if (!root)
    {
        printf("Tree is empty");
        exit(1);
    }
    tree_node *ret_val;
    if (root->left == NULL)
    {
        ret_val = root;
    }
    else
    {
        ret_val = min(root->left);
    }
    return ret_val;
}
tree_node *max(tree_node *root)
{
    if (!root)
    {
        printf("Tree is empty");
        exit(1);
    }
    tree_node *ret_val;
    if (root->right == NULL)
    {
        ret_val = root;
    }
    else
    {
        ret_val = max(root->right);
    }
    return ret_val;
}
```

> complete [code](https://gist.github.com/Sanusihassan/f968b1d6d16af80f97661459d14fed7a)